# Spring Data JPA findAll with table in between (PropertyReferenceException)

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, jpql

Here is my model:

- one AdmisHistory is linked to many Admis
- one Admis is linked to 0 or one AdmisRejet

Entities:

```
public class AdmisHistory {
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "admisHistory", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Admis> admis = new ArrayList<>();

public class Admis {
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = ADMIS_HISTORY_ID)
    private AdmisHistory admisHistory;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "admis", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private AdmisRejet admisRejet;

public class AdmisRejet {
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = ADMIS_ID)
    private Admis admis;
```

**Given an AdmisHistory, I want to retrieve the list of AdmisRejet.**

I manage to do it like this:

```
public interface AdmisRepository extends CrudRepository<Admis, Long> {
    List<Admis> findAllAdmisByAdmisHistory(AdmisHistory admisHistory);
...

// It work llike this:
 admisRepository.findAllAdmisByAdmisHistory(admisHistory)
.stream()
.filter(adm -> adm.getAdmisRejet() != null)
```

Now I would like to do it in a simple call on a repository. It would be much more efficient and readable.

Something like this:

```
 public interface AdmisRejetRepository extends CrudRepository<AdmisRejet, Long> {
        List< AdmisRejet> findAllAdmisRejetByAdmisHistory(AdmisHistory admisHistory);
    }
```

But I get this error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property history found for type Admis! Traversed path: AdmisRejet.admis.'
```

I try with @Query but the syntax is not good:

```
public interface AdmisRejetRepository extends CrudRepository<AdmisRejet, Long> {
    @Query("SELECT a " +
            "FROM AdmisRejet ar " +
            "LEFT JOIN ar.admis a, " +
            "LEFT JOIN a.admisHistory ah " +
            "WHERE ah = :admisHistory")
    List< AdmisRejet> findAllByHistory(AdmisHistory admisHistory);
}
```

How can I do it ?

Comment: Annotate your method with `@Query`, and specify the appropriate JPQL query as value of the annotation. Automatic queries derived from method names are only appropriate for simple stuff like findByName().

Comment: @JBNizet Incorrect; Spring Data can generate traversal queries like that just fine. The problem is with the relationship model, both because `admiss` is not `admis` and because the mappings don't seem to match cleanly.

Comment: @chrylis admiss -> admis (typo error). Do you mean that 'List<Admis> findAllAdmisByAdmisHistory(AdmisHistory admisHistory);' is the correct way to generate transversal query? and that the problem come from my entities ?

Comment: It's a little hard to tell exactly what your object graph is supposed to mean (particularly because of the opaque join table), but you don't specify the root object, and I *think* what you want is `List<AdmisReject> findAllByAdmisAdmisRejet(AdmisHistory)`. That said, because of the reuse of `Admis` over and over, it would probably be *clearer* to write your query directly in JPQL and name the method something readable.

Comment: Tried with @query but I can't find the correct syntax (see edit)

Comment: @chrylis That's exactly why it's not appropriate to use method name query derivation in such cases: finding the correct method name is harder that finding the JPQL query, and when you've found it, the method name is ugly, and too long. Just because something can be done doesn't mean that it's appropriate.

Comment: The simplest query is `select ar from AdmisRejet ar where ar.admis.admisHistory = :admisHistory`. If you prefer explicit joins, you can use `select ar from AdmisRejet ar join ar.admis a where a.admisHistory = :admisHistory`. Your query is wrong because it has an extra comma inside and doesn't select the right alias. Inner joins are fine here, too, and the last join isn't necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm reading the spec correct this should work.

```
@Query("SELECT DISTINCT ar 
        FROM AdmisRejet ar
        WHERE ar.admis.admisHistory = :history")
List<AdmisRejet> findAdmisRejetByAdmisHistory(AdmisHistory history);
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
  List< AdmisRejet> findAllAdmisRejetByAdmisHistoryWhereAdmisRejecIsNotNul(AdmisHistory admisHistory);
```

or something similar.